# How to remove files not containing string? - Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i want to remove all files not containing string "EXAMPLE STRING" in current folder.
How to do that?

I tried to, somehow, change this:

```
  for /f "eol=: delims="  %F in ('dir /b /a-d * ') do find "EXAMPLE STRING" %F > nul && del "%F"
```

But this deletes files with my string, not without.
How to make a command that would delete all files without string "EXAMPLE STRING"?

Comment: Use the other conditional operator.

Comment: 1. use `||` instead of `&&`; 2. double percent signs like `%%F` to use the code in a batch file;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find "EXAMPLE STRING" %F > nul &if errorlevel 1 del "%F"

Answer (score 0):

Use the other conditional operator.

&& - run the next command if the previous command succeeded.

|| - run the next command if the previous command was not true.

```
for /f "eol=: delims="  %F in ('dir /b /a-d * ') do find "EXAMPLE STRING" %F > nul || del "%F"
```